# Sonar version 3.6 required for local analysis

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

Coming across "Sonar version 3.6 is required to perform local analysis" message
when try to use Sonar Local Analysis in eclipse.

I just installed latest from [CodeHaus](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse)

where the Compatibility Matrix is saying it 3.6+.

I am using Eclipse: Juno 4.2, with following plugins installed:

1. Sonar Java Analyser 3.2.0.20130627-1142-RELEASE org.sonar.ide.eclipse.jdt.feature.feature.group SonarSource
2. Sonar m2e Connector 3.2.0.20130627-1142-RELEASE org.sonar.ide.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group SonarSource

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Are you running a sonarqube server?

I don't think you can use the plugin without the server running to connect to to do the analysis.

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SonarQube+in+Eclipse

For the purposes you are looking at, I am assuming personal use, you could probably get away with the standalone instance of SonarQube, using the H2 embedded database.

**Local Analysis Parameters**

Parameters to configure local analysis can be set in various places. Here is the hierarchy of parameters:

- Parameters defined in the SonarQube Web UI
- Parameters set in the pom.xml file (for Maven projects only, with the
  m2e connector installed) will override parameters defined in the UI
- Parameters defined in Eclipse will override  parameters defined in
  the pom file (go to Window > Preferences > Sonar > Local analysis
  properties)
- Parameters defined at project level in Eclipse will override
  parameters defined at Eclipse level (right click on the project and
  go to Properties > Sonar > Local analysis properties)

**Excluding Plugins**

Some plugins (useless for a local analysis) can be skipped while performing a local analysis thanks to the sonar.dryRun.excludePlugins property (Settings > Configuration > General Settings > General).

The default value is 'devcockpit,pdfreport,report,scmactivity,views'. For example, to skip the Build Stability plugin (due to https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARIDE-346), set the property to 'devcockpit,pdfreport,report,scmactivity,views,buildstability'.

Here is where I found this information: [Running Sonar Qube In Eclipse](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONARQUBE44/Browsing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse+-+Version+3.2)

**Double Check your settings**

You might also want to double check your settings.  The plugin will install the sonar instance for you for local analysis on localhost:9000.  If you deleted this, this might be giving you the errors.  You should have 2 servers listed on the config page, localhost, and your remote server

Refer back to this page too:  [Configuring Sonar With Eclipse](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/SonarQube+in+Eclipse)

Comment: Thanks. Yes the remote mode is working fine - i mean i can see violations in the Sonar Web Browser tab. Though its true that when i toggle modes (between local and remote) I do see a dialog launched saying : "Synchronize issues" has encountered a problem. Error during issue query org.sonar.wsclient.issue.IssueQuery@3094ce31

Comment: Can you update your post with your current sonar configuration?

Also with the project you are trying to run the analysis on, have you already run the analysis with sonarqube first before attempting with the eclipse plugin?

"To use SonarQube in Eclipse on a project, it is required that the project has been first analyzed by SonarQube."

Comment: Thanks. It has been analysed on SonerQube on a remote machine which i have no access to (besides using it as the SONAR server in eclipse for the remote analysis). So my only configuration is the 3.2.0 plugin mentioned.  I assume i do not need a local SonerQube installed?.

Comment: After reviewing some documentation, it seems that you do not need to run a local instance, as when you switch to local, it should automatically run an instance for you from eclipse.  I will update my answer with some documentation that I found that deals with the configuration that you might want to look into.

Answer (score 0):

With Sonar plug-in 3.0 local analysis could be launched fine.

With Sonar plug-in 3.2 I get the same error as you.

Please choose "Install new software..." and enter URL :

http://dist.sonar-ide.codehaus.org/eclipse-archives/3.0.0/

Comment: Thanks, its true 3.0 launched ok. Thing is i would like to use the latest plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I updated the eclipse plugin but forgot to update the sonar-server (SonarQube).

After following the upgrade guide and installing SonarQube 3.6.2 it worked again.