# Not possible to analyze locally in SonarQube

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, sonarqube

I have a [sonarQube](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Setup+and+Upgrade) server running on my work location.
I use the [eclipse plugin](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+in+Eclipse) to connect to the server and see the issues and run analyis.

My only problem is that I would like to be able to run analysis locally as well, when not connected to the network.

I looked up on the internet and [found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17492303/sonar-version-3-6-required-for-local-analysis) [several places](http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/Issues-when-trying-to-run-Local-Analysis-in-SonarQube-3-7-3-td5018717.html) with screenshots showing a "local analysis" option. I don't have that option available in my eclipse, for some reason

I have installed both the java sonarqube plugin and the m2e connector. The version installed is 3.3.0.

See screenshot for the available choices in my eclipse config : 
[image]

Any help to solve this would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You must have a connection to the SonarQube server to run an analysis.
The interface was simplified in version 3.3. Local analysis did not mean without connection to the server.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info! I have set up a local sonar server as well, allowing me to run analysis locally too now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Crtl + Alt + Q. This work perfectly for me in new and existing projects. You can see that option in the image attached.